# Flocking Algorithm Without Vectors?

Tags: java, algorithm, game-physics

I'm trying to implement a flocking algorithm for the enemies in my game for zombies so that they'll swarm together while avoiding colliding with each other. As of now, they just always move directly toward the player, which if the player moves around a lot, can cause them to stack on top of each other.

This has gotten me some feedback regarding the swarms of tiny zombies that all end up stacking because players shoot them (they're one-hit kills) and because there are more on top of them, they have been telling me that it looks like the bullet isn't hitting.

I've been looking into using a flocking algorithm, but the problem is that my game does not use vectors for enemy movement. I just have the enemy's position as an (x,y) pair and on update, they calculate their facing using atan2 and then update their position based on the cos and sin values of this theta.

I could add vector movement, but that would require a large amount of refactoring, so I would prefer to see if there's some way to implement this algorithm without that. This is the algorithm I have now. I know there are several flaws, but I expected to at least see some different behavior -- but the zombies still move exactly the same.

```
public void move(GameState gs, int delta) {
    theta = Calculate.Hypotenuse(position, Globals.player.getPosition());

    int neighbors = 0;
    float force = 0.0f;
    for(Enemy e : ((EnemyController)gs.getEntity("enemyController")).getAliveEnemies()) {
        if(!e.equals(this)) {
            float dist = Calculate.Distance(position, e.getPosition());
            if(dist < getSeparationDistance()) {
                // Add separation strength to theta.
                force += Zumby.SEPARATION_STRENGTH;
                neighbors++;
            } else if(dist < getCohesionDistance()) {
                // Add cohesion strength to theta.
                force += Zumby.COHESION_STRENGTH;
                neighbors++;
            }
        }
    }

    if(neighbors > 0) {
        force /= neighbors;
        theta += force;
    }

    if(!moveBlocked) {
        position.x += (float)Math.cos(theta) * Zumby.SPEED * delta;
        position.y += (float)Math.sin(theta) * Zumby.SPEED * delta;
    }

    moveBlocked = false;

    bounds.setCenterX(position.x);
    bounds.setCenterY(position.y);
}
```

I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Using a (pure) polar angle representation instead of Cartesian vectors is generally a very bad idea (you constantly need to account for the discontinuity at 180 degrees, especially when working with deltas). Also, adding a positive number `force` to the angle will not be very useful - you need to account for the direction that the force acts in. Also, since you already store positions as `(x, y)`, it should be fairly convenient to adopt vectors for this function alone.

Answer (score 0):

### Polar angle distance is a Vector

I am confused by your question.

> Flocking Algorithm Without Vectors?

But you do use vector math

```
position.x += (float)Math.cos(theta) * Zumby.SPEED * delta;
position.y += (float)Math.sin(theta) * Zumby.SPEED * delta;
```

You are adding the Cartesian form of the polar vector `{theta, Zumby.SPEED * delta}` to the Cartesian coordinate `position`

At any time you can convert from polar to cartesian and back as follows.

```
// description of polar and cartesian vector objects
polar = {angle, distance}
cartesian = {x, y}

// From polar to cartesian
cartesian.x = Math.cos(polar.angle) * polar.distance;
cartesian.y = Math.sin(polar.angle) * polar.distance;

// and cartesian to polar
polar.angle = Math.atan2(cartesian.y, cartesian.x);
polar.distance = Math.sqrt(cartesian.y * cartesian.y + cartesian.x * cartesian.x);
```

And some other vector functions (shortening the names `c = {x,y}` for cartesian and `p = {a,d}` for polar where `a` is angle and `d` is distance).

### Normalise

```
// cartesian
float length = Math.sqrt(c.x * c.x + c.y * c.y);
if (length > 0) {
    c.x /= length;
    c.y /= length;
} else {
    c.x = 1.0; // default vector or throw an error
    c.y = 0.0; 
}

// polar is too easy
p.d = 1.0;
```

### Rotate

```
// rotate where rotate is the rotation in radians

// cartesian
float dx = Math.cos(rotate);
float dy = Math.cos(rotate);
// c1 is a new vector
c1.x = c.x * dx - c.y * dy;
c1.y = c.x * dy + c.y * dx;


// polar is again too easy
p.a += rotate;
```

### Scale / multiply

```
// scale is the scaling 

// cartesian scale or multiply
c.x *= scale;
c.y *= scale;

// inverse or divide
c.x /= scale;
c.y /= scale;


// polar 
p.d *= scale;

// inverse
p.d /= scale;
```

### Add

```
// adding vector 

// cartesian 
c.x += c1.x;
c.y += c1.y;

// polar not too easy
float x = Math.cos(p.a) * p.d + Math.cos(p1.a) * p1.d;
float y = Math.sin(p.a) * p.d + Math.sin(p1.a) * p1.d;
p.a = Math.atan2(y,x);
p.d = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
```

### Which to use

You can do all the same operations with polar vectors that can be done with cartesian vectors. Some will be easier in one form than the other.

It is very easy to convert between the two forms so you dont need to refactor all the code. If you have an operation that you do not know the method for in polar, just convert to cartesian, perform the operation and then convert back to polar.

Comment: I meant specifically that I'm not using a Vector data structure, so I don't have a lot of those vector methods easily available. I was hoping I could avoid having to implement them for this one purpose. I suppose I can use Vectors for this method alone as meowgoesthedog recommended.